# Intersection of a conical hull with a halfspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider any $n$ $n$-dimensional vectors $v_{1}, v_{2}, \dots, v_{n} \in \mathbb R^n$, and any nonzero vector $u \in \mathbb R^n$. I want to intersect the space
$$
X = \left\{ \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \alpha_{i} v_{i} : \forall i\ldotp \alpha_{i} \ge 0 \right\}
$$
with the space
$$
Y = \{ x \in \mathbb R^n : u \cdot x \ge 0 \}.
$$
Are there vectors $w_{1}, w_{2}, \dots, w_{n} \in \mathbb R^n$ such that
$$
X \cap Y = \left\{ \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \alpha_{i} w_{i} : \forall i\ldotp \alpha_{i} \ge 0 \right\} ?
$$
If so, can you give a formula for a possible choice for the $w_{i}$?

### My Attempt

My guess is that you can let
$$
w_{i} = \begin{cases} 
v_{i}&\text{if $u\cdot v_{i} \ge 0$}\\
v_{i} - \operatorname{proj}_{u}(v_{i}) &\text{if $u\cdot v_{i} \le 0$}\\
\end{cases}
$$
but again, that's just a guess. I doubt it's that straightforward.

Comment: Are the $v_i$ meant to be orthogonal? I don't understand the term "quadrant" otherwise.

Comment: No, they're not; they might not even be linearly independent. I just couldn't think of a better word for the shape of $X$. Feel free to edit the title.

Comment: Wikipedia seems to call it a "conical hull", but I've never heard that before, have you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometrically the question amounts to: Does every intersection of $n$ half-spaces in $\mathbf{R}^{n}$, with the origin lying on the boundary hyperplane of each, have at most $n$ faces?

In the plane this is true, but in three-space it isn't: Think of a square-based pyramid with the origin at the vertex. Specifically, consider the vectors
\begin{align*}
  v_{1} &= (1, 0, 1), \\
  v_{2} &= (-1, 0, 1), \\
  v_{3} &= (0, 1, 1), \\
  u &= (0, -1, 1).
\end{align*}

Alternatively, consider the polyhedron obtained by slicing the conical hull trasversely to rays through the origin. Every interval ("polyhedron" in $\mathbf{R}^{2-1}$) has two endpoints, but for $1 < n$ not every polyhedron in $\mathbf{R}^{n-1}$ has just $n$ faces.

Comment: Just realized I mentally shifted notation while writing; my $v_i$ are not your $v_i$. But modulo notation the conclusion is unchanged.

Comment: Thank you, that was a very clear explanation.